# Change App name on Appstore while using same bundle identifier

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes

Is it possible to change App name while using same bundle identifier?

I have changed the name of the app while uploading a new version on iTunes but its only reflecting in iTunes but not in Appstore.

Please suggest the solution.

Regards

Comment: did you change new name in your project configuration?

Comment: Yes I have changed it as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the app name anytime and it has nothing to do with your bundle identifier.

Please note that there a different "places" to change the app name:

1) **iTunes Connect: "App Name" field** --> this is what gets displayed on the App Store

2) **Xcode: "Display Name" in General Settings** --> this is what will be displayed on the device when the app is installed below the icon

*Edit/Update on iTunes Connect:*

If you change the app name you will get this "warning" that the name change will only get deployed with the new version. (The version number doesn't play any role)

[image]

Comment: I have already changed it on iTunes but on Appstore its not updating name.

Comment: You have to upload a new version to change the App Name. You can edit it on iTunes Connect, but the changes won't go live w/o a new version.

Comment: I have already uploaded a new version? You mean to change version from 2.6 to 3? or 2.6 to 2.7 won't work?

Comment: The version number doesn't matter. Please check my updated answer for more information on the display in iTunes Connect. If you don't have the yellow dot and the highlight on the app name, it should end up in the store.  (Update roll-outs can take up to 48hrs)

Comment: I have already followed the same process as mentioned in your answer but it still show old name in Appstore.